# How to tombstone windows phone apps in c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna-4.0, tombstoning

How do I tombstone a csharp/XNA 4.0 app in csharp? Googling tutorials only shows how to do this in silverlight and the app I've made is in a visual studio 2010 Windows Phone Game project without silverlight.

Comment: You might wish to define the term "tombstone" in case someone knows how to do it (whatever it is) but doesn't know that term.

Comment: in short tombstoning is when a user on a phone pushes the home button on there phone then comes back to the game and its where they left off

Answer (score 1):

Something like [this](http://www.garethpw.co.uk/2010/11/tombstoning-in-phone-7-xna-games.html) or [this](http://fiercedesign.wordpress.com/2011/08/29/windows-phone-mango-tombstoning-xna/)?

Edit: This mind be also a good [link](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/article/tombstoning_wp7_games) to the problem

Comment: the second link didnt help but the first looks promising. Where is the source code for what he's refering too in his tutorial though? the download i got didnt tombstone itself when i tested it

Comment: I have no idea, i guess he means the code embedded in his post.
Please also have a look at [this](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/article/tombstoning_wp7_games)

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the Search button on your phone/emulator will tombstone your app. Same for the Start button.

Comment: maybe DORMANT maybe TOMBSTONE